# Erlang : convert [1,"aa","a1", 21]i into "(1, "aa", "a1", 21)"

Tags: string, list, erlang

Erlang: Turning a list like this:

```
[1,"aa","a1", 21]
```

into a string like this:

```
 "(1, "aa", "a1", 21)".
```

How can this be done?

Much appreciate.

Answer (score 4):

What was your problem?

```
(fun(List) -> lists:flatten(["(", string:join([io_lib:format("~p", [I]) || I <- List], ", "), ")"]) end)([1, "aa", "a1", 21]).
```

Answer (score 3):

I would think you were lookign for something like this :

```
1> lists:flatten(["(",lists:foldl(fun (X, "") -> 
    io_lib:format("~p", [X]);
                              (X, Acc) -> 
    [Acc, ",", io_lib:format("~p", [X])] end,
    "", [1,"aa","a1", 21]), ")" ]).

"(1,\"aa\",\"a1\",21)"
```

This is all about understanding iolists. we first create a list of the internal parts using a fold over the list :

```
Inner = lists:foldl(fun (X, "") -> 
                        io_lib:format("~p", [X]);
                        (X, Acc) -> 
                        [Acc, ",", io_lib:format("~p", [X])] end,
                    "", [1,"aa","a1", 21]),
```

and then wrap this

```
Wrapped = ["(", Inner, ")"],
```

and for the sake of pretty printing we flatten the list to make the final string:

```
lists:flatten(Wrapped).
```

And as is customary we then insert the expressions making one big, unreadable function as shown above :)